# High Value at Each Granularity

Tags: tableau-api

I have an table below which shows some data and I am trying to get the high value from each row.

Below is the data I have:

Table A

[image]

Once calculated it should looks like below in tableau

Table B

[image]

Notice that for Total, its not summing up from pers and bus instead its getting it highest value from total from table A and same concept is for Grand Total. Numbers which you see are balance.
I am able to get high value up to Total but its the grand total where I am struggling with. Below is my Calculation which I am using.

```
if 
countd([Category]) = 1 then 
sum({ FIXED [Group], [Category]: max(
{ FIXED [Group], [Category], [Date]: SUM([Balance])})})
ELSE
sum({ FIXED [Group]: max(
{ FIXED [Group], [Date]: SUM([Balance])})}
)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Step-1: For max of categories, use this calculation `desired maximums`

```
MAX({Fixed [MVRA Group], [Product Category], [Date Display]: ([Primary Measure])})
```

STEP-2: For max of subtotal, use `desired sub-total maximum`

```
MAX({Fixed [MVRA Group], [Date Display]: ([Primary Measure])})
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zyjCDdG_QECrkFgY-UFm7WM2yN1xaHmZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @Anil, Thank you for your help! I am still not able to get it. Since StackOverflow doesn't let me attach the file, I have uploaded it on google drive. Please see from below link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GYRJTOEbRd6eIs98Jy16xvOb3Vs9TaCX/view?usp=sharing

I have the calculation on New HIgh Value column, I have all the high value for each granularity except for grand total which is 640, 045,929

Comment: Hi Mr.Jin.  Though you have uploaded your worksheet, I needed to see the shape/format of your raw data, which I am unable to because the sheet is connected with some data source in SQL! Nevertheless, I am trying.  Give me some time

Comment: Without seeing your original data it is too difficult.  Nevertheless, I have tried.  see this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zyjCDdG_QECrkFgY-UFm7WM2yN1xaHmZ/view?usp=sharing